# An efficient way to list users information as someone type in the search box

Tags: php, ajax, search, asynchronous

**The problem** I'm facing now is to design an efficient live search in user search box.

**What I want is** If somebody starts typing then I should make a call to fetch appropriate users. As far as I know if I implement such a thing in AJAX way then PHP calls on the server side would be the bottleneck as it's not asynchronous.

**And I'm curious about** how different sites implement these features? Have you had the same problem? Should I use AJAX in some different ways? Or are there any other tools that I'm unaware of?

Please answer if you've had the same challenge before?

Comment: Actually, we are doing this and it works just fine on our system. There is a very very slight lag, but we are using a low-end CPANEL hosting service -- and speed is still acceptable. In fact, I've done this type of thing for several clients, almost always on low-end hosting services (like NameCheap -- value package, of all things). If speed is acceptable for my clients (again, lag is barely noticeable), it should be fine for you. Create a test case and try it.

Comment: Well, very good point. We're searching in the hundreds of items, not hundreds of thousands or millions, as a good social networking site will garner. Mind you, by the time you have that many users, you will be re-engineering your back end on several fronts, I would imagine. *I will remove this comment in a few mins, after you've had time to read it, so it doesn't clutter your question.* By the way, it shouldn't take too long to programmatically create a million-record user table and try the code to see for yourself. Nothing like first-hand experience.

Comment: Sorry, I keep revising above comment. Please refresh and re-read. I typically use MySQL with InnoDB tables, just "out of the box" so probably without caching. Honestly, this stuff is pretty fast. I'll drop a code sample for you, as an example of my simplistic methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [jQuery-ui Autocomplete widget](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/) is a good place to start.  It can be easily customized and is widely used.  It can easily handle both static data in a javascript variable or dynamic data from an ajax call.  It can be set to wait a specifed number of milliseconds so the search doesn't flood the server while a user is typing and can also be configured to require a certain number of characters before it will search so it doesn't return a huge result set.

Depending on the size of your data, you're probably going to want to use ajax with caching for the data source.  There's an example of this on the Autocomplete page.  If you will only be searching a up to maybe one hundred items max, static data in a javascript variable may be better, but it would need to be populated on each page.

If the search is just based on user names and the name starts with what is typed, the php side will be very fast since a database query should be very fast with an index.  Depending on your data, the search box in a "contains" mode probably won't be terribly slow.  If possible, you could also set up caching through memcached or something similar on the server side to cache searches which would make all requests potentially much faster.  The results could have an expiration time of a few minutes or longer depending on traffic how often the data might change.

Comment: Is it customizable to show user's pictures and their rank, name, etc.

Comment: @phpGeek You can specify a callback for the results so you can make it do whatever you want.  There is an example on the Autocomplete page that demonstrates custom data display.

Answer (score 1):

Code sample, using the jQueryUI autocomplete widget:

**jQuery/javascript: jQUI autocomplete**

```
$('#srchbks').autocomplete({
    source: "autocomplete_test.php",
    minLength: 2,
    select: function( event, ui ) {
        console.log('UI: ' + ui);
        console.log('Label: ' + ui.item.label);

        var srxs = $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'inc/index_booksTable.inc.php',
            data: 'request=get_books_like_srx&bookslike=' + ui.item.label,
            success: function(result) {
                $('.booksDIV').html(result);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

**jQuery/javascript: Pressing ENTER in search field populates books_DIV**

```
$('#srchbks').keyup(function(e) {
    var keycode = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
    if(keycode == '13'){
        var srch = $(this).val();
        if (srch.length > 1) {
            var srxs = $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'inc/index_booksTable.inc.php',
                data: 'request=get_books_like_srx&bookslike=' + srx,
                success: function(result) {
                    $('.booksTableDIV').html(result);
                    $('#srchbks').val('').blur().focus(); //clear srchbks field but remain inside.
                }
            });
        }
    }
});
```

**PHP SIDE:**

**autocompletetest.php:**

```
<?php


include 'fn/init.php';

$term = trim(strip_tags($_GET['term']));//retrieve search term sent by autocomplete
$term = $_GET['term'];

$qstring = "SELECT * FROM `books` WHERE `title` LIKE '%" .$term. "%'";
$query = mysql_query($qstring) or die(mysql_error());
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($query);

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
    $row['title']=htmlentities(stripslashes($row['title']));
    $row_set[] = $row['title'];
}
 if ($num_rows_returned > 0) {
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            $r = $r . '<option value="' .$row['id']. '">' . $row['name'] . '</option>';
        }
    } 

echo json_encode($row_set);
```

**index_booksTable.inc.php**:

```
<?php

$rBooks = get_all_books();
$out = '';

while ( $aRow = mysql_fetch_assoc($rBooks) ) {
    $avg = $aRow['up'] - $aRow['dn'];
    $aUser = get_user_data($aRow['rated_by']);
    $out .= '
            <div id="bid-'.$aRow['bid'].'" class="bookList_DIV">
                <div id="thumb-'.$aRow['bid'].'" class="bookThumb_DIV">
                    <img src="img/cov-' .$aRow['bid']. '.jpg" />
                </div><!-- #thumb -->
                <div class="bookDetail_DIV">
                    <p>
                        <span class="bookTitle_SPAN">' .$aRow['title']. '</span>
                        <span class="bookAuthor_SPAN">' .$aRow['author']. '</span>
                        <span class="bookIsbn_SPAN">ISBN: ' .$aRow['isbn']. '</span>
                    </p>
                    <p class="bookReason_P">' .$aRow['rcats']. '</p>
                    <p class="ratingInfo_P">
                        <span class="rateDate_SPAN">' .$aRow['date_rated']. '</span>
                        <span class="ratedBy_SPAN">' .$aUser['username']. '</span>
                        <span class="userPoints_SPAN">(' .$aUser['points']. ')</span>
                    </p>
                </div><!-- .bookDetail_DIV -->
            </div><!-- #bid .bookList_DIV-->
        ';
}

echo $out;
```